# Como mostrar as consultas geradas pelo EF core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Um tempo atrás, com um simples código dentro do meu contexto, mostrava as consultas geradas pelo EF6 no console ou até mesmo escrevia em um arquivo txt...

Contudo, hoje uso o Entity Framework Core, numa aplicação asp.net core(MVC) e queria fazer o mesmo, alguém tem ideia de como faço isso?

Comment: Você tentou o  `UseLoggerFactory()`?

Comment: Não, mas vou pesquisar sobre e implementar, vlw!

Comment: Se encontrar alguma dificuldade, edite a sua pergunta com a tentativa e a gente resolve ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer é implementando um provedor de log.

Em sua classe de contexto do EF você sobrescreve o método `OnConfiguring` informando o provedor de log que você irá criar:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    var lf = new LoggerFactory();
    lf.AddProvider(new MyLoggerProvider());
    optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(lf);
}
```

Para criar seu provider, crie uma classe (nesse exemplo criei a classe *MyLoggerProvider*) que implemente a interface `ILoggerProvider`.

Implemente nela o método `CreateLogger` retornando uma instância de classe (nesse exemplo criei a classe *MyLogger*) que implementa `ILogger`, ao implementar o método `Log` dessa interface, você especifica o caminho do arquivo.

Feito isso ao rodar a aplicação o log com as consultas do EF será gerado.

Abaixo o código das classes criadas:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.IO;

public class MyLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        return new MyLogger();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    { }        
}

public class MyLogger : ILogger
{
    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(@"C:\temp\logDaAplicacao.txt", formatter(state, exception));
        Console.WriteLine(formatter(state, exception));
    }

    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Esse exemplo, eu encontrei [aqui](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/6482#issuecomment-300952277) e testei local para validar, funcionou direitinho.

Na [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging) também tem exemplo de como logar no console.